# Move navigation menu to header

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

how can i upload the navigation menu for the header and edit the menu layout

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code your default.xml and run the `php bin/magento c:f`

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.panel"/>
```

After you want to right position so add this css and after check you output

```
nav.navigation {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.